# What are the odds of rolling a 1 and a 20 in two d20 dice?

Tags: probability, dice

So, one of these days a friend of mine rolled two d20 dice and got a $1$ in one of them and a $20$ in the other. I was thinking, what are the odds of this happening?

Comment: Are the two roll independents ? Yes (hopefully), and what is the odd of obtaining a 1 ? what is the odd of obtaining a 20 ? Then how can you combine ?

Comment: He rolled the two dices simultaneously, and got a 1 and a 20.

Comment: What do you think?  It's 1 in 20 that he gets a 1 on the first die and it's  1 in 20 that he gets a 20 on the second.  So what is the probability that he gets a 1 on the first and he gets a 20 on the second?  What is the probability of the opposite (a 20 on the first, and a 1 on the second)?   What is the probability that he gets either a 1 on the first and a 20 on the second OR he gets a 20 on the first and a 1 on the seccond?

Comment: There's a huge amount of possible combinations when you roll two dices

Comment: @P.Quinton as a more knowledgeable mathematician guiding a less experienced one you should probably talk of "probabilities"; not "odds" and not encourage the less experienced into bad habits.  Probilities are the likelihood of an event  compared with*in* all possibilities (e.g. 1 in 6 or $\frac 16$; you have 1 chance of rolling a three from the 6 possible rolls) odds are the likelihood of an event compared *to* (and against) the likelihood of *other* events. (e.g. $1$ to $5$ or $1:5$; you have $1$ chance of rolling a three compared the the $5$ chances of not rolling a three)

Comment: "There's a huge amount of possible combinations when you roll two dices"  Yes.  But how many?  You can answer that.

Comment: The *method* is the same as if you were doing somethings smaller.  Try it with three sided die.  What is the probability of rolling a 1 and a 3.  The method will be exactly the same.  (Hint and warning: Rolling a 1 on the first and a 3 on the second is *one* event and rolling a 3 on the first and a 1 on the second is another.  Don't calculate them as one.  Pretend one die is green and the other is red and calculate the probability that he rolls a 1 on the green and a 3 on the red OR the other way around.)

Comment: @ParclyTaxel  To cut and paste:  "Joestar Jones is a new contributor. Be nice, and check out our Code of Conduct. "

Comment: I really don't know how to approach the problem. Some of my friends though it was just a 1 in 40 chance, which obviously is not true. I thought it could be 20x20 or maybe 20!, but I'm not an "experienced mathematician", so maybe you could teach me? I would be really glad to learn a way to solve this kind of problem

Comment: @fleablood I'm sorry, he already has the point. The comments are going smoothly.

Comment: " I thought it could be 20x20 or maybe 20!"  You thought *what* could be 20x20 or 20!?  "so maybe you could teach me".  Like I said try it with three sided dice.  Take a piece of paper.  make table with two columns; one for the green die and one for the red.  In the columns list all the options from one to three.  How many combinations are there?  How many of them are either (1,3) or (3,1)?  Now do the same for two 4 sided dice.  What are you answers.  What bath did you do and why did it work.  Imagine 20.  Always google "probability and dice".

Comment: https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability "One of the most interesting things about chance is that to figure out the probability that two things will both happen you multiply their two probabilities together."  And https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability#Independent_events

Answer (score 2):

On a D-20 dice there are 20 possible outcomes.  The probability of rolling any particular face of the dice (assuming that it is a fair dice) is ${1}\over{20}$.  These events are independent of each other, this means that the outcomes of the dice do not influence each other.  To find a particular two dice combination we have to take the probability of the first outcome and multiply it by the probability of the second outcome.
$$\frac{1}{20} * \frac{1}{20} = \frac{1}{400}$$
The chance of rolling a one and a 20 is $\frac{1}{400}$.  This is actually the same probability as any particular combination of those two dice.  For example, rolling a 3 and a 16 would also be a $\frac{1}{400}$ probability.

Since there are two possible ways to get the combination of one and 20, first dice is one and second is 20, or first dice is 20 and second is one.  You add the two probabilities together
$$\frac{1}{400} + \frac{1}{400} = \frac{2}{400} = \frac{1}{200}$$

This is the final probability of this event.

Comment: This is incorrect.  The probality of rolling a 1 on the first die and a 20 on the second is $\frac 1{400}$ and the probability of rolling 20 on the first die and a 1 on the second is $\frac 1{400}$.  But because those are the **TWO** ways to roll a "1 and a 20" the probability is $\frac 2{400}= \frac 1{200}$.

Comment: Good point. I will ammend.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine the two dice are different colors.  One is blue and the other green.

There are $20$ possible options the blue die can roll.  For each of those $20$ there are $20$ possible options there green die can roll.  So there are $20*20 = 400$ possible outcomes.  Each one is equally likely.

There are $2$ ways to roll a $1$ and one and a $20$ on the other.  Either the blue die is $1$ and the green die is $20$, or the green die is $1$ and the blue die is $20$.

So out of the $400$ possible outcome $2$ of them are a $1$ and a $20$.

So the probability is $\frac 2{400} =\frac 1{200}$.

BTW.  That is "probability".  Technically "odds" is a different concept.  The odds of rolling a $1$ and a $20$ are $2$ in favor to $(400 - 2)$ *against*.  Or $2$ in favor to $398$ against.  Or reduced proportionally $1$ in favor to $199$ against.  Or simply, $1$ to $199$ or $1:199$.